# Error 405 on PUTs, "ignoreme.rastahook" in IIS log

Tags: openrasta

We have an Asp.Net application with OpenRasta, and when we deploy it on most of our IISes (7.5), it works fine. In one installation though, for PUT requests, the client receives "405 Method not allowed" errors, and the log shows entries like:

> 2011-11-15 01:18:20 192.168.0.164 PUT /myapp/ignoreme.rastahook - 80 - 192.168.0.131 AClient 405 0 0 57

*ignoreme.rastahook* seems to come from OpenRasta's rewriting in OpenRastaModule.cs:

> HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~/ignoreme.rastahook"), false);

The GETs and POSTs work fine though, not sure though if the HTTP method really is what makes the difference. Any idea on what might be going on or where to start debugging? My current guess would be some IIS configuration difference between the working servers and the one that doesn't.

OpenRasta version is 2.0.3, and we run the app on .net 4.

**Update:**
Fwiw, when changing the *verb* attribute of the OpenRasta handler mapping from "*" to "GET,POST" in the web.config of my server that works, I get a "ignoreme.rastahook" in the log file as well for the PUTs, but with a 404, not a 405, so that seems to be different from the issue described above.

**Update 2**
I figured that when I enable WebDAV, I can reproduce the 405 / ignoreme.rastahook issue. Which lead me to https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki/Installing-OpenRasta-Under-IIS , that states that

> please be aware that the WebDAV module can cause problems with IIS 7.5

**Update 3**
I verified that **WebDAV is what caused the problem** on that other server, but if anyone knows how to fix the problem without disabling WebDAV altogether, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as you've seen comes from WebDAV. There is no know way that I have found bar adding the entries in your web.config to disable webdav.

This has been added to [the wiki page](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki/Installing-OpenRasta-Under-IIS) in question.

Comment: Could you please add the wiki page you are referring to, the one that shows how to do it in web.config. I can't seem to find it - I tried to google both "site:openrasta.org webdav" and "site:github.com/openrasta webdav" without success.

Comment: added the link, the config is in the "405 errors on PUT" section of that page.